# git command to emit name of remote tracking branch

Tags: git, branch

I'd like a command that emits the name of the tracked branch for the branch I'm on.  Something like:

```
$ git checkout --track -b topic origin/master
Branch topic set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'topic'
$ git unknown-command
origin/master
```

Is there such a command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Will emit the remote being tracked:

```
git config branch.<branchname>.remote
```

Will emit the ref being tracked on that remote:

```
git config branch.<branchname>.merge
```

I don't believe that there is a combined command that will emit both together (at least within normal Git; you could always make your own).

---

For example, for a local `master` branch:

```
$ git config branch.master.remote
origin
$ git config branch.master.merge
refs/heads/master
```

Comment: With recent versions of git, you can emit the name of the remote-tracking branch for your current branch with `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u}`. It emits something like refs/remotes/origin/master. If you ignore the "refs/remotes" bit, this is exactly what was asked for.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard: could you post that suggestion as a new answer?  It's very useful, and not prominent enough at the moment, I think...

Answer (score 23):

As per Mark Longair's request, my previous comment is now reproduced as an answer.

With recent versions of git, you can emit the name of the remote-tracking branch for your current branch with `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u}`. It emits something like refs/remotes/origin/master.

If you go one step further and use the `--abbrev-ref` flag, as in `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref @{u}`, it will strip off the `refs/remotes/` bit and leave you with just the short branch name, such as `origin/master`.

Comment: Another way is `% git for-each-ref --format='%(upstream:short)' $(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)`, but I like yours better.

Comment: found a scenario where this trick does not work: i rename the local branch with git branch -m and then push it in order to create a new remote branch ; now after that the value returned by your command ( git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u} ) is the old branch name (the remote branch that was before renaming of the local branch) - i would have expected the name of the new remote branch.

Comment: @MichaelMoser: You renamed the local branch and pushed it, but you didn't update the upstream tracking information. You can use the `-u` flag to `git push` to change the upstream tracking information.

Answer (score 5):

```
git config --global alias.show-upstream '!sh -c '\''

    test -n "$1" || set -- HEAD
    set -- "$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "$1")"
    git for-each-ref --format="%(upstream:short)" "$1"


'\'' -'

git show-upstream
git show-upstream HEAD
git show-upstream some/local/branch
```

Answer (score 3):

As of git 1.8.3 you can now do this:

```
git branch -vv
```

Very convenient as it shows the tracking branch for all local branches at once, but it is not suitable for scripting.