# git hooks post-merge

Tags: git, heroku

Is there anyway to tell whether or not the merge made was associated with a pull?

I'd like to use git-flow's merges as a hook to send my data to heroku.  Ideas?

Comment: I don't understand - why particularly do you need to know whether a merge was the result of pull?  Surely with the git flow model you just care whether the merge was into `master` or some other particular branch?

Comment: I am trying to run a deploy script to heroku everytime I merge into master, however, I also have a staging server and would like to deploy to the staging everytime I merge into development.  There are 2 of us collaborating and I'm worried that everytime we will pull from origin and it will auto-merge into development, it will try again to publish to the staging...

Comment: Do you mean that you're worried that if you run `git pull origin master` while you're on the `development` branch, it will deploy a version to the staging server that has changes from `master` merged?

Comment: No.  I'm worried that which ever branch i'm on it wil deploy everytime I run "git pull origin master/development". I just dont want it to push for nothing when I don't need it to.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't like this arrangement: every merge into master or development that you try locally would cause a deploy, and I'd much rather make deploying the code an active decision - there's no room to try merging something without deploying it.  (Also, I don't know about Heroku's behaviour exactly, but I would be surprised if it redeployed when pushing a commit to a ref that wouldn't change that ref.)  Finally, often the merge that is done by a pull will not be a fast-forward, so there *will* be a new version of the code to deploy.

However, if you really want to do this, you can do the following in a script:

```
UPSTREAM=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u})
```

That will give you the remote-tracking branch that represents upstream of your current branch - in a post-merge hook your current branch is the one that you've just merged into.  (That nice command is taken from Kevin Ballard's comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763039/git-command-to-emit-name-of-remote-tracking-branch/3763075#3763075).)  You can find the object name (SHA1sum) of that commit with:

```
UPSTREAM_OBJECT_NAME=$(git rev-parse --verify $UPSTREAM)
```

Then you want to find out if that commit was one of the parents of HEAD - you can get the parents with:

```
HEAD_PARENTS=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%P")
```

... so can test for whether upstream was one of the parents with:

```
git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%P" | grep -q $UPSTREAM_OBJECT_NAME
```

Finally, you should check the first line of the reflog for the remote-tracking branch to check that it was last updated via a pull.  In other words, does the line:

```
git reflog show -n 1 $UPSTREAM
```

... contain `pull : fast-forward`.

That should give you the pieces you need for `post-merge` script of the type that you want.  To reiterate, though, I really wouldn't want this ;)