# Git : How to get name of the branch tracked by the current one?

Tags: git, branch, remote-branch

In order to write a specific script, I need to check is the current branch has a tracked remote and what is the name of this remote. Is there a way to get only the name of the branch tacked by the current one, without having to parse `git remote show origin` output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git command to emit name of remote tracking branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763039/git-command-to-emit-name-of-remote-tracking-branch)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since 28fb8438 (Introduce @{upstream} notation, 2009-09-10) included in Git 1.7+, you can use the `HEAD@{upstream}` (or `HEAD@{u}` for short) to achieve this.

For educational purposes, here's a shell script equivalent.

```
#!/bin/sh

cbranch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
cmerge=`git config branch.$cbranch.merge`
cremote=`git config branch.$cbranch.remote`
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$cremote/`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref $cmerge`"
else
    return 1
fi
```

Comment: Yep, his answer's more terse.