# how to check a local branch tracking which remote branch?

Tags: git, git-branch

I want to check a local branch currently tracking which remote branch

For example:

```
git checkout -b test_branch
git branch --set-upstream test_branch origin/remote_project001
```

But after a few days, I forget which remote branch `test_branch` is tracking.
Is there a command that can give me that information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git command to emit name of remote tracking branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763039/git-command-to-emit-name-of-remote-tracking-branch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763039/git-command-to-emit-name-of-remote-tracking-branch), but to briefly repeat that for your situation, you can do the following:

```
$ git checkout test_branch
$ git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}
origin/remote_project001
```

If you get the error:

```
error: No upstream branch found for ''
@{u}
error: No upstream branch found for ''
fatal: ambiguous argument '@{u}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

... then there is no remote-tracking branch configured to be upstream of your current branch.